# StorageReferenceId for JWT Input Claim in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

What value should I have for StorageReferenceId when passing a JWT as in InputClaims to a user journey?

[In the sample for WingTip Games](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_invitation.xml), a value of `WingTipsGamesClientSecret` is used.  Where did that come from?  Where is that value defined?

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Invitation">
  <InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="WingTipGamesClientSecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Invitation">
  <InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_StackOverflowKey" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

`IEF -> Policy Keys -> Add`

[image: IEF Policy Keys]